# take user input and activate and de activate a function at specified times

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

Right so I'm building a time lapse program to run on my pi.
I've used a tkinter entry widget to take an on time and another entry widget for an off time and then save them to a list.

The problem I'm having is figuring a way to compare these variables against a clock and have an event triggered and deactivated at certain times.

Basically for arguments sake the user enters 07:00 for on and 13:00 for off, then at 7am the function for the camera becomes active, then at 13:00 it becomes inactive. A simple Boolean can be turned on and off to activate the code for the camera.

Got everything else working but just can't figure the best way to compare the variables against time, everything I have tried has failed miserably.

Any help please

================

## update:

so firstly thank you both for your replies, i have made this test app and it sort of works how i want it now

```
import time, Tkinter as tk
camera =  False
on_time= '17:48'
off_time= '07:55'

class App():
  def __init__(self):
    self.root = tk.Tk()
    self.root.geometry("50x50")
    self.label = tk.Label(text="")
    self.label.pack()
    self.checkTime()
    self.root.mainloop()
  def checkTime(self):
    time_now = time.strftime("%H:%M")
    self.root.after(1000, self.checkTime)
    if time_now >= on_time and time_now <= off_time:
      camera=True
      self.label.configure(text=camera)
      print camera
    else:
      camera=False
      self.label.configure(text=camera)
      print camera

app=App()
```

it works just fine if on_time is smaller than off_time but not the other way round, so if i want the camera to come on at 07:00 and off at 17:00 that would work fine but if i wanted it to come on at 17:00 and off at 07:00 it won't work.

i just need to figure out a better way to compare the variables. am i on the right track

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing I can suggest would be to have a background thread that has an infinite loop checking the time and setting boolean values as is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Tkinter widgets provide an [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) method that arranges for an arbitrary function to be executed from the main loop after a specified number of seconds.

Since you need your function to run at a specified **time**, you can simply use `after` to schedule the function to run every minute, checks the current time, and set the appropriate flags. Or, you can make the code more correct and calculate the exact amount to wait using the `datetime` module, call `after()` with that period, and then simply turn the checkbox on/off.